# Calculate sum of inputs from two tabs and paste it in textInput box - Shiny R

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server, shinydashboard

```
`if (interactive()) {

ui <- fluidPage(
numericInput("obs", "Observations:", 10, min = 1, max = 100),
numericInput("obs1", "Observations1:", 10, min = 1, max = 100),
textInput("final", "Sum")
)
server <- function(input, output) { 

}
shinyApp(ui, server)
}
```

`

How do I use the inputs from Observations and Observations1 and paste the value in the Sum.

I tried, input$obs + input$obs1 in server and it didn't work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand the difference between your inputs and your outputs.
You should watch the first 30-45 mins of [this video.](https://vimeo.com/rstudioinc/review/131218530/212d8a5a7a#t=0m0s) But I believe the below will do what you have asked.

ui.R

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(

  numericInput("obs", "Observations:", 10, min = 1, max = 100),
  numericInput("obs1", "Observations1:", 10, min = 1, max = 100),
  textOutput("sum") 
))
```

server.R

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
    output$sum <- renderText({input$obs + input$obs1})

})
```